# Wamp/DynDNS/IP i can't configure

Tags: ip, wamp, router, dyndns

I have a problem with wamp, dyndns and my public IP.

I have everything set up and when I go from my computer to my public IP takes me to the router.

When I access from my cell phone that is connected to my wifi to my public IP takes me to the router.

And when I access from my phone without being connected to my public IP does not take me anywhere.

In the router I have configured my DynDNS account with my domain.

Also I have configured the port 80 to my local ip.

I have also configured the DMZ to my IP.

I have also set "Port Triggering" on port 80 to my local ip.

Do not know how to configure it to do well.

Can you help?

Thank you.

P.D: sorry for my bad English, I'm Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you dont want your PC configured to be in the DMZ. Very dangerous and not necessary.

Here is what I do.

I use DYNDNS so this should work.

First setup your domainname on DYNDNS's wabpages.

Then download the
[DYNDNS updater](http://dyn.com/support/clients/windows/installguide/),

it runs on one of your PC's and every time you boot your router or it chnages its WAN IP address this spots the change and tells DYNDNS to updates its DNS's.
Using this you dont need to setup your router to know anything about DYNDNS.

You then just need to setup `Port Forwarding` on your router so the routers `port 80` is forwarded to your PC that runs WAMP.
You will need to make sure that this PC has a static IP address, not one allowcated by the DHCP server in the router. This ensures that the Port Forwrding will always find the correct PC.

Then you will need to change the security in Apache.
The simple way is to use the wampmanager icon and just `left click -> Put Online`
If that does not work, and it does not always, you can manually edit httpd.conf again using the wampmanager menus system.
`left cick wampmanager->Apache->httpd.conf`

Look for this section of httpd.conf

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

And change it to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Finally i buy a host but when i'll have time i try it.